# Outputting SQL SERVER Query Results to CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I'm using a basic query to gather data from a few joined tables, and I need to be able to export the data to a CSV (or text) file in order to be imported into Excel.  The query format is:

```
SELECT  
Item1 as 'blah'  
FROM  
table1 JOIN table2  
WHERE Condition  
GROUP BY ...  
HAVING ....
```

I have the proper output setup correctly through the query, so I'm only looking for a way to output it to a file.  If it would be easier to use a stored procedure, then it would be no problem to throw that around the query. I'm just looking for something that can write the output to a file, WITHOUT using a third-party tool, as this needs to be moderately portable.

If you need more detail from the query, I can supply that (but it really is basic).

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio will allow you to pipe the results to a file.  While not a CSV initially, it'll get you most of the way.

Comment: @paqogomez - I was trying to avoid using the built-in SQLSMS output, as I'm not sure if the person running the SQL will have the SQLSMS software on their machine.  Thank you, though!

Comment: What is executing the query?

Comment: Use the import/export wizard. Comes with all versions AFAIK and can export a custom query to delimited flat file or Excel native.

Answer (score 3):

Use a BCP utility [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

That's what most commonly used.

Comment: This is probably the right technology, but it might be a bit premature because OP hasnt specified what is actually going to be running the query.

Comment: So this may be my lack of experience with SQL (especially BCP), but when I attempted to use it before, I ran into issues where I was using characters in the query, such as:

WHERE value = 'Bryan'

Is there a way in the BCP syntax to include strings with the ' marks, or does it need to be an external or stored procedure?

Again, I apologize for how elementary this may seem.

Comment: Try using CHAR codes for the single quote symbol. Example: WHERE value = char(39) + Bryan + char(39)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to SSIS (through the Business Intelligence Development Studio), create a data flow task with an OLE DB Source going to a Flat File Destination.  Or, you can go straight to Excel, if you don't want to worry about converting the delimited file.